# Latex setcounter(subsection)

Tags: sectioning

Good day, (texlive debian buster) I want my tableofcontents  to to start with 3.4, section works but subsection always starts at 1, no matter where I put the setcounter, thanks

```
 \begin{document}
  \setcounter{subsection}{3}
  \setcounter{section}{2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't know/will do. To me LaTex is a sort of programming lang for building boring tenders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the subsection counter after you actually start the section, because at the start of a section, the counter is reset to zero

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{section}{2} 
\section{title}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\subsection{title}

\end{document}
```